# Silverlight and Thickbox

Tags: jquery, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, thickbox

I am having some trouble with silverlight's z-index. I have a thickbox dialog that pops up but my silverlight gallery is still pulling up on top, hidden most of the modal dialog. Has anyone experience this problem? I have tried bumping up the z-index on the thickbox control but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to ensure that you can display HTML content over Silvelight you need to run the Silverlight plug-in with the Windowless setting.  In the set of param elements in your `<object>` tag include:-

```
<param name="windowless" value="true"/>
```

Now the Thickbox should appear over the Sliverlight control. Note that there may be some draw backs with this approach especially in performance.  Its not recommended if your app is displaying video.